# Where can I find the implementation for std::string

Tags: c++, string, header, implementation

I am looking for the code for the c++ string class. What header is it implemented in?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is no single implementation for `std::string`. But you can find your particular implementation in the `<string>` header.

On my system it can be found here:

`/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.0/include/g++-v4/bits/basic_string.h` and `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.0/include/g++-v4/bits/basic_string.tcc`

On a Debian-based system:

```
~$ locate basic_string.tcc
/usr/include/c++/4.5/bits/basic_string.tcc
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/basic_string.tcc
~$ locate basic_string.h
/usr/include/c++/4.5/bits/basic_string.h
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/basic_string.h
~$
```

Generally, you are going to be looking for the `basic_string` template, since `std::string` is just a specialization of that.

Comment: Thank you. It appears only the prototype of the method I was looking for: find() is in there "size_type find(const _CharT* __s, size_type __pos, size_type __n) const;"

Comment: ahhh sorry. I've found it in basic_string.tcc. Thanks!

Comment: gcc implementation is here: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.1/libstdc++/api/a01053_source.htm

Answer (score 0):

As you might expect,

```
<string>
```

which will most likely be located in whatever `include` directory your compiler has as its base.

Comment: you are of course right, but keep in mind that (IIRC) `<string>` doesn't actually have to be an actual file. I never seen an implementation where it wasn't though...

Comment: It isn't a file on VMS; header files are contained in 'text libraries', whatever they are. Why, I've no idea.

Answer (score 0):

It's in `<string>`. It's a header file distributed with your compiler. It may include other (private) header files - a lot of the implementation for Visual Studio is in a file named "xstring".

Answer (score 0):

A similar question with the answer for Visual Studio:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17205896/5520058

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\crt\src\
```

The version and location of Visual Studio can be changed. This is the default installation path where the sources can be found.

Visual studio versions:

> - 2005 -> 8
> - 2008 -> 9
> - 2010 -> 10
> - 2012 -> 11
> - 2013 -> 12
> - 2015 -> 14