# c++ Why is memory allocated when passing a string literal to a function?

Tags: c++, string, memory-management

I have his code:

```
int setAttrib(const string& name, int components){    
    // here I don't even touch 'name'
    if(components == 2) return 3;
    else return 1;
}
```

And I call the function this way:

```
setAttrib("position", 3);
```

I'm profiling memory with xcode profiler and in the function call std::string is making an allocation.
Why is that?

**EDIT:**

What's the best way to avoid that allocation? since I'm calling that function **a lot**, and in about 10 seconds of time I end up allocating about 10MB in that line.

Thanks.

Comment: It depends on your compiler. Some compilers will not allocate dynamic memory for such a short string. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466073/how-is-stdstring-implemented](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466073/how-is-stdstring-implemented)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You ask for a `const string&`, but pass in a `const char*`. The compiler thus needs to create a temporary object of the correct type.

The fact that `"position"` is not an `std::string` but a `char const*` is more of a historical accident (inherited from C, when there was no `string` class in C++) than a design decision, but something to keep in mind nevertheless.

Comment: +1 Since this is the only response which seems to hit on the key issue: a string literal doesn't have type `std::string`.

Comment: workaround for "multiple" allocations, is to make static std::string attrName("position") one line before setAttrib("posisition"...) and replace const literal with attrName variable

Comment: @Kamil: you could even define it in the namespace, as a constant.

Answer (score 6):

Because `std::string` typically allocates heap memory to hold the string. In this case, a `std::string` is implicitly constructed from a string literal (which by itself resides in static storage). Some string implementations use a small buffer to serve small strings, but this doesn't seem to be the case here and is implementation-dependent anyway.

It doesn't matter that `name` is not used - basically, `setAttrib("position", 3)` is shorthand for `setAttrib(std::string("position"), 3);`, so when control enters `setAttrib`, the memory has already been allocated (of course, in your isolated code sample it would be possible for a compiler to inline `getAttrib` and then drop the string construction at all, but this is a compiler optimization, not a language feature).

Note that temporary objects created during function invocation are automatically destructed when the function returns, so there is no memory leaked.

Comment: "and then drop the string construction at all" constructors are never optimized out.  They could have side effects a la RAII.

Answer (score 5):

In order to call the function the compiler needs to construct ***all parameters***, `const string& name` included, the only way to do that in your case (you pass a string literal instead) is to construct a temporary `std::string` and this requires a heap memory allocation in most implementations. It doesn't matter if you use the value inside the function or not.