# What is the difference between char stringA[LEN] and char* stringB[LEN] in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

I read a few similar questions, [C: differences between char pointer and array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335786/c-differences-between-char-pointer-and-array?lq=1), [What is the difference between char s[] and char *s?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704407/what-is-the-difference-between-char-s-and-char-s-in-c), [What is the difference between char array[] and char *array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21225189/what-is-the-difference-between-char-array-and-char-array) but none of them seem to clear my doubt.

I'm aware that

```
char *s = "Hello world";
```

makes the string immutable whereas

```
char s[] = "Hello world";
```

can be modified.

My doubt is if I do `char  stringA[LEN];`  and `char* stringB[LEN];` Are they any different? Or does `stringB` again becomes immutable as in the case before?

Comment: The difference is that an array is an array and a pointer is a pointer. A pointer is not an array, and an array is not a pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are they any different?

Yes.
Both variables `stringA` and `stringB` are arrays. `stringA` is an array of `char` of size `LEN` and `stringB` is an array of `char *` of size `LEN`.

`char` and `char *` are two different types. `stringA` can hold only one character string of length `LEN` while elements of `stingB` can point to `LEN` number of strings.

> Or does `stringB` again becomes immutable as in the case before?

Whether strings pointed by elements of `stringB` is mutable or not will depend on how memory is allocated. If they are initialized with string literals

```
char* stringB[LEN] = { "Apple", "Bapple", "Capple"};
```

then they are immutable. In case of

```
for(int i = 0; i < LEN; i++)
    stringB[i] = malloc(30)  // Allocating 30 bytes for each element  

strcpy(stringB[0], "Apple");
strcpy(stringB[1], "Bapple");
strcpy(stringB[2], "Capple");
```

they are mutable.

Answer (score 6):

Let me give you a visual explanation:

[image]

As you can see, `a` is an array of 4 characters, whereas `b` is an array of 4 character pointers, each pointing to the beginning of a C string. Each one of those strings can have a different length.

Answer (score 3):

They are not the same.

Here `stringA` is an array of `char`, that means printing `stringA[0]` will show the letter `S`:

```
char stringA[] = "Something";
```

Whereas printing `stringB[0]` here will show `Something` (array of pointer to char):

```
char* stringB[] = { "Something", "Else" };
```

Comment: The second part of your answer should contain stringB and not stringA

Answer (score 2):

They are not having the same datatype, less being comparable.

- `char  stringA[LEN];` is a `char` array of `LEN` length. (Array of `char`s)
- `char* stringB[LEN];` is a `char *` array of `LEN` length. (Array of `char` pointers)

FWIW, in case of `char *s = "Hello world";` `s` is a pointer which points to a *string literal* which is non-modifiable. The pointer itself can certainly be changed. Only the content it points to (values) cannot be changed.

Answer (score 0):

The reason

```
char* s = "Hello World!";
```

is immutable is because `"Hello World!"` is stored in RO(Read Only) memory, sow hen you try to change it, it throws an error. Declaring it as a pointer to the first element of an "array" is NOT the reason it's immutable. You seem to be slightly confused as well.

Assuming your questions is exactly what you mean,

```
    char stringA[LEN] = "ABC";
```

is a string in traditional C style, but `stringB` as you've defined isn't a string, it's an array of strings -

```
    char* stringB[LEN] = {"ABC", "DEF"};
```

Assuming you mean what I think you mean,

```
    char stringA[LEN] = "Hello World!";
    char *stringB = malloc(LEN);
    strcpy(stringB, stringA);
```

In this case, stringB IS mutable, since it refers to writable memory.