# How string library works in C++?

Tags: c++, string

According to the text at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/, string library in C++ is a class, not just a " mere sequences of characters in a memory array".
I wrote this code to find out more:

```
string s = "abcd";

cout << &s << endl; // This gives an address
cout << s[0] << endl; // This gives 'a'
cout << &s[0] << endl; // This gives "abcd"
```

I have some questions:
1. Is string library in C++ still an array of sequence characters?
2. How can I get the address of each character in string? (As in the code, I can retrieve each character, but cannot get its address using `& operator`)

Comment: 1. No. But the `std::string` *type* *contains* a sequence of characters. 2. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: You may read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466073/how-is-stdstring-implemented

Comment: There's a handy function: c_str(). Use it as so: `string MyString; /*populate it*/ char* MyCharacterArray = MyString.c_str();`

Comment: @Shingetsu: ...but avoid `c_str()` when you can (which you usually can).

Comment: @jerry why would it be avoided? if done once and saved I don't see a problem in using it. please enlighten me, I always like finding out new things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Much (most) of this really isn't about the string class itself.

`std::string` does store its contents as a contiguous array of characters.

`&s[0]` will yield the address of the beginning of that array -- *but* `std::ostream` has an overload of `operator<<` that takes a pointer to char, and prints it as a string.

If you want to see the addresses of the individual characters in a string, you need to take their addresses *and then* cast each address to pointer to void. `std::iostream` also has an overload of `operator<<` that takes a pointer to void, and *that* overload prints out the address instead of a string that (it assumes) is at that address.

Edit: demo code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(){
    std::string x("this is a string");

    std::cout << &x[0] << "\n";
    std::cout << (void *)&x[0] << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
this is a string
00481DE0
```

Answer (score 0):

std::string stores the string as essentially a vector of characters, see [basic_string](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/basic_string.html)

Answer (score -1):

From Stroutrup's book, chapter 20 on strings, page 579 (2000 edition)

`From C, C++ inherited the notion of strings as zero terminated arrays of char....`. In C, the name of the array is same as the address of the first character. That's why you get the whole string printed when you pass `&s[0]` as it same as passing `s` itself.

Comment: Actually there's a bit of luck involved - `&s[0]` isn't zero-terminated (at least in the 2000 edition); you may get any number of junk characters. That's because `std::string` uses a stringlength. Now, in some cases, the number of junk characters can be 0, and you'd get the result that ipkiss did.

Comment: Is it not that `&s[0]` same as `s` ? I remember to have read this from K & R.

Comment: If and only if `s` is a C-style array, and even then only after array-to-pointer decay. (e.g. `sizeof(s)` generally isn't `sizeof(&s[0])` ). But read the question again: `s` is a `std::string` here, with an overloaded `operator[]`. K&R doesn't apply at all.