# How to store C type "char *" to c++ vector?

Tags: c++, string

In c++ code, I have to call a C function which is returning "char*". I want to store the return string in a C++ vector.

> Since the C function returning "char *" present in a different
>   shared object, I cannot not modify it.

Declaring vector as `vector<string>` and storing C type char* is fine or is there any better way i can achieve it?
I tried the bellow code snippet and don't see any warning or error.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<string>
#include<cstring>
#define MAX_LEN 100
using namespace std;

/*
 * In my actual project, the C functions resides in different shared object.
 * So i cannot modify it. Here I just added the function (fun1, fun2 and fun3)
 * in same file to  minimize the code.
 */
extern "C" {
 char* fun1(char *str1) {
        snprintf(str1, MAX_LEN, "%s", "string 1");
        return str1;
 }
 char* fun2(char *str1) {
        snprintf(str1, MAX_LEN, "%s", "string 2");
        return str1;
 }
  char* fun3(char *str1) {
        snprintf(str1, MAX_LEN, "%s","string 3");
        return str1;
 }
}
int main() 
{ 
        vector<string> V_str;  //defined vector which can store string element
        char *str_ptr, buffer[MAX_LEN]="\0";
        str_ptr = fun1(buffer); // adding char* to the vector
        V_str.push_back(str_ptr);
        str_ptr = fun2(buffer);
        V_str.push_back(str_ptr);
        str_ptr = fun3(buffer);
        V_str.push_back(std::string(str_ptr));
        for(unsigned int i = 0 ; i < V_str.size(); i++ ) {
            cout<<V_str[i]<<endl;
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
string 1
string 2
string 3
```

Comment: Relevant: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/190716/is-relying-on-implicit-argument-conversion-considered-dangerous I think it’s fine here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pointers and Strings C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20794832/pointers-and-strings-c)

Comment: Leaving your question aside, here's a short advise: Document who owns the things who's address you pass around. If you start documenting that for your functions above, you will find that the returnvalue is completely useless. Then, think about what that does to your question, in particular what parts are now irrelevant.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Eckhardt Thanks for your comments.  I added the explanation in the code snip.

Comment: That update explains your goal a bit more, @NaveenKumar. However, what we still don't know is why the functions return the exact same string that you pass to them, which seems kind of silly and redundant. Also, I wonder whether the actual code behaves like that. If it did, you could create a suitably sized `std::string` and pass the address of the first character to the function. Also, you could discard the result of the function call, as you know that value already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code is *almost* fine. The only potential pitfall is the fact that your `fun*` functions to not accept the length of the buffer. This is unsafe and frowned upon. Normally, function signature would be something like `char* fun1(char* buffer, size_t sz)` and it would check the size of the buffer before using it.

However, assuming the C function is given (seeming to be the case from the question), and you can't do anything about it, the code is perfectly fine.

Since one of `std::string` constructors take `const char*` argument, `std::vector<std::string>.push_back(const char*)` creates a temporary string and moves it to the vector. From now on, vector owns this string. This is safe and is not subject to any memory leak.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I update the code snip with buffer overflow check.

Comment: @NaveenKumar `strncpy` is really the wrong function to add a buffer overflow check, if the function gets a too long string, it will not 0-terminate the result "string" ("string" instead of string, because without a 0-terminator at the end, it is not a string).

Comment: Yes, better use `strlcpy` if it is available or null-terminate yourself.

Comment: I have added snprintf