# What goes on when you concatenate a char to a string in C++?

Tags: c++, string

For example, the following code reverses a string, but what actually goes on when I'm adding each character to a string? Is it efficient? Does it create a new char array every time, or does it double the size every time it fills up, or?:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string test = "testing";

    stack<char> first;

    for(int i = 0; test[i]; i++)
    {
        first.push(test[i]);
    }
    string reversed;
    int i=0;
    while(!first.empty())
    {
        reversed += first.top();
        first.pop();
    }
    cout << test << reversed;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use [std::reverse](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse)?

Comment: Read this SO post to know how `string` works http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466073/how-is-stdstring-implemented

Comment: The use of the stack is unnecessary and adds an unneeded inefficiency. A more efficient way would be `string reversed(test.rbegin(), test.rend());`.

Comment: @all The question is about using string as a efficient source not about reverse

Comment: @Shan Yet the most efficient way to create a string which is a reversed version of another one is probably the one I showed.

Comment: @juanchopanza sorry if I wasn't clear in my question but Shan is correct. I do not care about the efficiency of reversing a string in my example, I only included that as an example to show what I was asking. My question is only about what happens when adding a character to a string.

Comment: You could print `reversed.capacity()` in every iteration and see how many times string buffer is resized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a string is added to another string, in the case of + operator, the resultant string is move constructed.

String a("hello");
a+="goodmorning";

A string uses a  char buffer underneath, and the size is set to default value at construction time.You can alter it using reserve.But during concatenation, if the reserved size is exceeded, then the buffer has to be extended.

Answer (score 1):

Yes the code is non-efficient. You should use [std::reverse](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse). But if you still want to stick with your approach, use [std::string::reserve](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/reserve) to increase the capacity of string.

```
string reversed;
reversed.capacity(test.size());
```

---

When you add character by character to `std::vector` and `std::string`, they resize when the capacity is exhausted by a constant factor. (typically 2, but may be different)

This [exponential growth](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/9380/why-is-push-back-in-c-vectors-constant-amortized) makes sure that cost of insertion is constant asymptotically.

Comment: I guess he is asking about `string` library not about reverse.

Comment: Sorry, I knew that the stack was inefficient, but I was primarily wondering about the actual string concatenation part of it and what happens when you add a character to the string that way. I understand there are better implementations of reverse and even one in the standard library, but just wanted to give an easy to follow example for adding characters to a string.