# string to struct in C++

Tags: c++, string, struct

I have a string variable

```
string pr00("")
```

and I want to call the method fun1

```
fun1(demo *dm)
```

demo defined as follow

```
typedef struct 
{
    char pr00[100];
}demo;
```

is that safe to call this method as

```
fun1((demo*)pr00);
```

thanks and BR

Comment: No, this is not safe. This is **very** unsafe, `std::string` is a complex structure, very different then your `demo` struct. For starters they are of different size. Not to mention that the standard explicitely marks casting between unrelated structs/classes as UB. Don't do that.

Comment: no it isn't safe to cast a `std::string` to a `char*` use `std::string::data()`

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466073/how-is-stdstring-implemented) SO question may be interesting for you.

Comment: why would you think it is?  You wouldn't randomly cast other classes to be other random classes would you?

Answer (score 2):

No, this is unsafe. Because `std::string`'s members are not the same as `demo`.

But you can define a constructor to implicitly convert `std::string` to `demo` type.

```
#define MAX_SIZE    100
struct demo 
{    
    demo(const std::string& str)
    {
       memset(pr00, 0, MAX_SIZE);

       if (str.length() < MAX_SIZE)
       {
           strncpy(pr00, str.c_str(), str.length());
           pr00[str.length()] = 0;
       }
    }

    char pr00[MAX_SIZE];
};
```

Now you can write code as this:

```
std::string name("hello world");
demo d(name);
```

Comment: With a user-defined constructor , demo is not a POD, see [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178175/what-are-aggregates-and-pods-and-how-why-are-they-special](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178175/what-are-aggregates-and-pods-and-how-why-are-they-special).

Comment: @cwschmidt Good catch! But as I read in the thread, it mentions *user-defined copy-assignment operator and destructor*, not constructor.

Comment: @MartinZhai Picking the specific quotes:  "An aggregate is an array or a class (clause 9) with no user-declared constructors"    ...   "A POD-struct is an aggregate class"

Comment: In the `str.length() >= MAX_SIZE` case you are leaving `pr00` uninitialised

Comment: @Caleth  Yes, but we can't know the length of string in compile time. In order to deal with strings with any length, we need to use dynamic allocated char string. I'm not sure if that's what OP wanted.

Comment: @UKMonkey Oops.. My mistake.

Comment: @MartinZhai I mean you can zero initialise it, or copy 99 characters and nul terminate, or copy 100 characters.

Answer (score 1):

No, `fun1((demo*)pr00);` is undefined behaviour. You will need to copy (at most 100) characters from `pr00` into a `demo` and pass a pointer to that to `fun1`

```
demo dm;
std::copy_n(pr00.data(), std::min(100, pr00.size()), dm.pr00);
fun1(&dm);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming `string` means `std::string`.

It's not just unsafe but invalid. The question has `fun1((demo*)pr00)`.

This is an attempt to cast a structure to a pointer. Illegal and if your compiler has settings where that is allowed, turn them off.

There's a slightly more interesting question regarding `fun1((demo*)&pr00)`.
Notice the `&` taking the address of `pr00`.

It's still undefined behaviour but at least it's converting pointers between unrelated structures.

You could define `void fun2(char*cp)` and call `fun2((char*)&pr00)` though what you can safely do with `cp` inside `fun2()` has a number of restrictions.

You shouldn't make any assumptions about the layout of `std::string` so you should' access `cp` (and particularly not write to it) with any assumption of what you might find.